# How to create conditional text in Libreoffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I want to create a template for a contract document and maintain several options within the same ODT file instead of maintaining multiple files for each variant of the contract. This means that some paragraphs should be optional and some parts of the text have two alternatives.

I tried to do this using hidden sections or conditional text (as described here https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Conditional_Text or https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/6/6d/0214WG3-WorkingWithFields.pdf) but find it very impractical and limited. Especially the following issues:

- conditional variables are stored in the text instead of document properties (why???); yes, they can be hidden, but then the manipulation is even more difficult
- custom properties cannot be used in conditional expressions (or I haven't found a way to do so)
- hidden sections within numbering still allocate the number, so the numbering in the printout is non-continuous
- conditional text cannot hold formatting

Is there some more convenient and more competent way of creating such a conditional text in LibreOffice Writer?